# Where did Og get his name from?

Tags: names, matzah, og

I am looking for sources for the name of Og

I have seen the midrash ([DR 1:25](https://www.sefaria.org/Devarim_Rabbah.1.25?with=all&lang=bi)) which explains the source of the name Og as related to the making of matzot/ugot/cakes.

Are there any other sources for this unusual name?

Comment: Why are you interested specifically in Og as supposed to any other name? For that matter, why do you expect there to be any sources that explain his name (besides for the midrash that you mentioned)? Adding those in would improve the question IMO

Comment: What makes "Og" any more an unusual name than "Buki ben Yogli", head of the tribe of Dan?

Comment: ...or any less question worthy than Aharon and Miriam?

Comment: @Loani Actually, Seder Olam Rabba [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Seder_Olam_Rabbah.3.2?vhe=Seder_Olam,_Warsaw_1904&with=all&lang=bi) and Pesikta Rabbati ([here](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesikta_Rabbati.15.1?vhe=OYW&with=Tanakh&lang=bi)) provide an explanation for Miriam, while Yalkut Shimoni ([here](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah.165.2?with=all&lang=bi)) provides explanations for both Miriam and Aharon.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Aggadah%2C_Deuteronomy.3.11.5?vhe=Midrash_Aggadah,_ed._Buber,_Vienna,_1894.&lang=bi

Comment: @Oliver I wasn’t trying to say that they don’t have answers, just that it makes as much sense to ask about them as Og.

Comment: Maybe from ogre